# how to make API calls inside for-loop one by one

Tags: node.js, api, musixmatch

im currently working for a webapp using nodejs . this is my first time using Node.
I have an items in array(topsongs_s[]) that will be pass (one by one) as an arguments  to modules function tht get a data from a musixmatch API .

modules : https://github.com/c0b41/musixmatch#artistsearch
example given in the modules :

```
music.artistSearch({q_artist:"prodigy", page_size:5})
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
})
```

and here is my code :-

```
for (let index = 0; index < topsongs_s.length; index++) {
              var artistName = topsongs_s[index].artists[0].name; //get the artist name in the array
              console.log(artistName); //print the artist name

              music.artistSearch({
                q_artist: artistName, //pass the artist name 
                page_size: 1
              })
              .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data.message.body.artist_list[0].artist.artist_id); //print the artist_id from musixmatch api
                console.log();
              }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
              })
}
```

i'm using a for loop to get the artist name from  an array , and pass it into the modules function . but it seems that the function get the artist ID without a proper iteration. i want it to be run one by one
is there any other way to do this kind of operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `async/await`

I have added comments in the code snippet for the explanation, it pretty straightforward.

```
// you need to add "async" keyword to your function
// to use async/await functionality
async function callAPI() {

    for (let index = 0; index < topsongs_s.length; index++) {

        // use try/catch for error handling
        try {
            var artistName = topsongs_s[index].artists[0].name; //get the artist name in the array
            console.log(artistName); //print the artist name

            // call synchronously and wait for the response
            const data = await music.artistSearch({
                q_artist: artistName, //pass the artist name 
                page_size: 1
            });

            console.log(data.message.body.artist_list[0].artist.artist_id); //print the artist_id from musixmatch api
            console.log();

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

}
```